# UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "**.lib.so" has unexpected e_version: 65725

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
Process: example.some.ed4.di, PID: 13990
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/example.some.ed4.di-X5PrLl2fWMuTOoeqKz3DaQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libgeneraldecryptjni.so" has unexpected e_version: 65725
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1071)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
at pas.system.InitJni(system.java:13)
at pas.system.<clinit>(system.java:137)
at pas.system.InitJni(system.java:11)
at pas.system$PascalObject.<clinit>(system.java:21)
at pas.generaldecrypt$T34KmeDecrypt.Create(Native Method)
```

Problem when I'm trying to use .so lib in android app App.
build.gradle

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
```

folder libs is inside src/main

[image]

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Well, how was `libsomejni.so` created? What do `file` and `readelf -h` have to say about it?

Comment: @Botje I doubt it's a valid ELF file - the only valid value for `e_version` that I can find is 1.  Every ELF file I looked at on multiple Linux (RHEL and Ubuntu) and Solaris 11 systems has `e_version` set to the value `1`, and `elf.h` on both Linux and Solaris define `EV_CURRENT` to `1`.  See both https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/gabi4+/ch4.eheader.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: This question needs more details in order for anyone to answer.

Comment: Easy to say afterwards but that was my conclusion as well :-) the file _does_ contain an Elf header though so I am curious what it then turns out to be...

Comment: @Botje I'm not sure of that.  From what the OP has posted so far, all we know is the implementation of `dlopen()` used found `65725` where `1` was supposed to be.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Fair remark, but the ELF header [*is* the first thing checked before looking at e_version](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:bionic/linker/linker_phdr.cpp;l=232-313?q=%22unexpected%20e_version%22&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain)

Comment: @Botje So what writes an ELF file with e_version not 1?  AFAIK that's the only valid value ever for ELF files of any type.